# Header Background Not Displaying on Github site, works fine on local host

Tags: javascript, html, css, github

So, I've been setting up a website for my church camp. I downloaded a template, personalized it, and everything looked fine running locally through my computer (Firefox). However, when I uploaded it to Github, the main header background does not show up, but simply is white. Nothing shows up, nothing changes. When I check the local file, it shows up perfectly. Is there something that I'm missing? I am hosting it through Github pages, at https://tjsanzen.github.io/camp

I've tried changing all the CSS, I've tried changing the HTML, making sure the databases are updated, nothing seems to work. No matter what I do, it continues to stay a white blank background.

You can view all my code for it at https://github.com/tjsanzen/camp

It should have the picture of the kids walking up the hill as the background, and works fine on other pages, but instead no matter what I do, it remains a white screen. I'm not sure what is wrong, but any and all help would be appreciated!

Comment: you need to create github page to see your contents of the repo. follow the tutorials https://pages.github.com/

Comment: Github is not a web host. To view a website you need a web host. Github offer one, called Github Pages, so that might be the easiest way for you to go. But you mention databases - I didn't see any database in your code after a quick glance, but if you need database hosting then you might need a different web host.

Comment: Ah yes sorry, I forgot to mention that I was indeed hosting with Github pages. I'll edit the post:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS, you reference `img/header.jpg`, but in your repo, that image is uploaded as `img/header.JPG`. Changing the case should fix it.

Your operating system probably has case-insensitive file names, making `JPG` effectively the same as `jpg`, which is why it worked on your localhost. For GitHub Pages, apparently, file names are case sensitive. This could be because the servers running Pages have case-sensitive file names, or because the application interpreting the HTTP requests enforces case sensitivity.